# Issue when upgrading SSIS with Script tasks to .Net runtime 4.7.2

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, upgrade

I have some SSIS packages to be upgraded to SQL Server 2019 and Visual Studio 2019. The problem is in the script tasks , when i try to change the target runtime .NET version to 4.7.2 the build succeeded. however after closing the script and reopening it i could still see the target version is reverted to 4.7 and the build failed.

Any ideas/suggestion, please let me know.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Open up the csproj file with notepad and change.  Do you have write permission for the csproj file?  Modifying in VS should permanently changed the value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However there is no csproj file. instead there is dtproj file and i am unable to find the version. In solution file, if i open in notepad i can find the old VS2013 version.

Comment: You need a csproj.  Do a File : SaveAll after upgrading.  Also see : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba0ae861-2320-42c4-b4e4-1c2856266006/visual-studio-not-supporting-dtproj-following-installation-of-other-tools-in-visual-studio?forum=ssdt